# Python project packaging

Tags: python, import, packaging, python-packaging

As a beginner in Python, I would like to properly package my project. To simplify the resolution, I built a simple project with the following tree:

```
.~/python_ws/my_project
├── classes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_class.py
├── __init__.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main.py
```

What I want is to access the class `My_class` defined in `my_project/classes/my_class.py`; in `my_project/src/main.py`.

I saw that it was essential to have an empty `__init__.py` in my main package and into sub-packages.
Here are my codes:

**my_project/classes/my_class.py :**

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self, my_attribute):
        self.my_attribute = my_attribute


    def print_my_attribute(self):
        print(f"{self.my_attribute}")
```

**my_project/src/main.py :**

```
from my_project.classes.my_class import My_class # Or from ..classes.my_class import My_class

instance_of_My_class = My_class("My attribute")
instance_of_My_class.print_my_attribute()
```

To me, the import seems legit, but it actually, VSCode keeps telling me `Import "my_project.classes.my_class" could not be resolved`.
I ran the code but indeed, the import successfully didn't work :

```
my_VM@my_VM-virtual-machine:\~/python_ws/my_project$ python3 src/main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/my_VM/python_ws/my_project/src/main.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from my_project.classes.my_class import My_class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'
```

I feel that I miss something important in the configuration of my project that may be obvious, but as a beginner, I don't really see what's wrong.

Do I have to deal with the `PYTHONPATH`? Do I need to create or define other things to better define my project?

Comment: Try putting `main.py` in the root directory.

Comment: @Mr.Fegur This works, but isn't there any solution such that I can just store my main in src ? In my real project, I have many other files from which I must access to the classes and I don't want to just throw them in the root folder ...

Comment: python does not allow this on the basis that it would open the code to circular references. i always find that one level of nested folders is the most you want to get to.

Comment: Just put the `main.py` file in the root folder and every other file in a subfolder.